# Recreating Stack Exchange Tutorial Snippet

Tags: tikz-pgf

I came across a Stack Exchange tutorial snippet in one of the more recent [issues](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf)  of [TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/) and wanted to make it in TikZ.

[image: Desired SE Tutorial Snippet]

I'm having trouble recreating the fountain pen voting signs, replicating the checkmark, and putting the title in a shaded box.

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (top box) [draw=gray, align=center, rounded corners, text width=3.5cm, minimum width=4.5cm] at (0,1.5) {Click here to \textit{upvote} any useful post};
\node (bottom box) [draw=gray, align=center, rounded corners, text width=3.5cm, minimum width=4.5cm] at (0,0) {Click here to \textit{accept} the best answer to your question};

\node (upvote) [draw, circle, color=gray, above left = 0.1 and 1 of top box.west] {up};
\draw [->, >=stealth, color=gray] (top box.west) -- (upvote);

\node (votes) [color=gray, below = 0.2 of upvote] {1};
\node (downvote) [color=gray, below = 0.2 of votes] {down};

\node (best answer) [draw, color=gray, circle, below left = 0.1 and 1 of bottom box.west] {\checkmark};
\draw [->, >=stealth, color=gray] (bottom box.west) -- (best answer);

% surrounding box
\coordinate (top right) at ($(current bounding box.north east) + (1,1)$);
\coordinate (bottom left) at ($(current bounding box.south west) - (1,0.3)$);
\draw [color=gray, thick, rounded corners] (bottom left) rectangle (top right);

\node (box title) [above = 0.3 of upvote] {How to thank};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My SE Tutorial Snippet]

Thank you very much for your help with this :)

Comment: There are lots of symbols you can use, such as \filledmedtriangleup and \filledmedtriangleup from MnSymbol, or \Checkmark from bbding.  See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiwt8rmgeLjAhUNPq0KHUbJBhAQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Finfo%2Fsymbols%2Fcomprehensive%2F%3Flang%3Den&usg=AOvVaw2c3jISre3RnnvKIm02F7Qw

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you for adding the TikZ drawings! Tcolorbox has very friendly syntax, and I'll definitely use \tikzset in the future; it makes everything look cleaner. I didn't know you could control in and out angles for lines.. good to know! Thank you very much for taking the time to respond :D

Comment: Prof. van Duck is very happy of it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prof. van Duck is very sorry because you will probably be disappointed, but the fountain pen and the checkmark were simply a clipping of a screenshot of the TeX.SE site at the time when the article was written.

If you save this picture as `tick.png`:

[image]

and you compile this document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
    enhanced,
    before skip=6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    after skip=6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    unbreakable,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    halign=center,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxed title style={colback=yellow!70!white}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={How to thank},
        attach boxed title to top, top=0pt]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            tondo/.style={circle, draw=orange, thick, text width=1.5em},
            quadro/.style={%
                rounded corners, draw=orange, thick, 
                align=center,
                font={\small},
                text width=12em,
                minimum height=9ex
            },
            freccia/.style={orange, thick, -stealth}
            ]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (foto) {\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{tick}};
            \node[tondo, below=6pt of foto.north, anchor=north] (upv) {};
            \node[tondo, above=1pt of foto.south, anchor=south] (acc) {};
            \node[quadro, right=10em of upv.north, anchor=north] (dupv) 
                {Click here to \emph{upvote} \\ any useful post};
            \node[quadro, right=10em of acc.south, anchor=south] (dacc)
                {Click here to \emph{accept} \\ 
                the best answer to your question};
            \draw[freccia] (dacc.west) -- (acc);
            \draw[freccia] (dupv.west) -- (upv);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

You'll get:

[image]

However, it is very simple to recreate those symbols in Ti*k*Z, here they are:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, fit}
\tikzset{
    fountainpen/.pic = {
        \node[circle, fill=lightgray, inner sep=.9pt, outer sep=0pt](start){};
        \draw[#1, lightgray] (start) -- (0,.5);
        \draw[#1, line width=1pt, lightgray] (0,.5) to[out=-80,in=130] (.2,.05) to[out=-100,in=90] (.17,-.11) -- (-.17,-.11) to[out=90,in=-80] (-.2,.05) to[out=50, in=-100] cycle;
    },
    checkmark/.pic = {
        \fill[lightgray] (0,0) to[out=60, in=210] (.25,.25) -- (.25,.43) to[out=220, in=70] (-.01,.1) to[out=100, in=-45] (-.1,.24) -- (-.2,.15) to[out=-30, in=130] cycle;
    },
    tondo/.style={circle, draw=orange, thick, text width=1.5em},
    quadro/.style={%
                rounded corners, draw=orange, thick, 
                align=center,
                font={\small},
                text width=12em,
                minimum height=9ex
            },
    freccia/.style={orange, thick, -stealth}
}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
    enhanced,
    before skip=6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    after skip=6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    unbreakable,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    halign=center,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxed title style={colback=yellow!70!white}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={How to thank},
        attach boxed title to top]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pic[local bounding box=penhigh] {fountainpen};
            \node[text=gray, below =7pt of penhigh] (one) {1};
            \pic[local bounding box=penlow,  below =10pt of one] {fountainpen={rotate=180}};
            \pic[local bounding box=check,  below =24pt of penlow] {checkmark};
            \node[tondo] at (penhigh) (upv) {};
            \node[tondo] at (check) (acc) {};
            \node[quadro, right=10em of upv.north, anchor=north] (dupv) 
                {Click here to \emph{upvote} \\ any useful post};
            \node[quadro, right=10em of acc.south, anchor=south] (dacc)
                {Click here to \emph{accept} \\ 
                the best answer to your question};
            \draw[freccia] (dacc.west) -- (acc);
            \draw[freccia] (dupv.west) -- (upv);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]